# In Javascript, how do I make a function calls a specific function before executing anything within it?

Tags: javascript

In Javascript, how do I make a function calls a specific function before executing anything within it (similar to super.func in an OO language)?

e.g.

```
function test() {
  // would like this to call a custom function
}

function test2() {
 // would like this to call the same custom function
}
```

The idea of this is so I can achieve things like logging out what function gets called, without having to inject the log statement to the beginning of every single function.

Comment: I don't think I understand your question, but wouldn't it just be adding the name of the function and parenthesis? `test3()`

Comment: JavaScript is a pretty darn OO language, unless you were mincing words there.

Comment: @Oka Not suggesting Javascript is OO or otherwise, just want to achieve the super.function() in OO in Javascript and not sure how.

Comment: @Boon: Not sure I understand what you mean by `super.function()`. Wouldn't that be a statement that had to be injected in the beginning of every single function?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript does not have such a feature that can be done in an automatic way.  You'd have to replace `test` and `test2` with something else that calls your logging thing and then calls the original.

For example, here's a generic function that can hook any other function and call your log thing first:

```
function test() {
  // your function that does whatever
}

// function hooker
function logFunction(fn, logFn, arg) {
    return function() {
        logFn(arg);
        return fn.apply(this, arguments);
    }
}

// custom function to be called by the hook function before executing original function
function myLogger(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
}

// then to hook something
test = logFunction(test, myLogger, "test");
```